# Replace string with line break with another string in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to replace

```
$fieldTool.GetFieldValue($i
    tem,"Title")
```

with

```
{{(sc_get_field_value i_item 'Title')}}
```

The original string has a line break and I am using `'n` like this `$fieldTool.GetFieldValue($i'ntem,"Title")`

This is the code

```
  $template = '<div class="tile-inspiration__title field-title">$fieldTool.GetFieldValue($i
  tem,"Title")</div>'
  $matchString = '$fieldTool.GetFieldValue($i'ntem,"Title")'
  $pattern = $([regex]::escape($matchString))
  $replaceString = "{{(sc_get_field_value i_item 'Title')}}"
  $newtemplate = $template -replace $pattern, $replaceString
  Write-Host $newtemplate
```

The above code is not working. How can I replace the string with line break with another string.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if it's just here because of the formatting but instead of a single quote 'n you should use a backtick for your linebreak pattern `n

Comment: @Theo that's not necessary, on input output it'll be automatically replaced by `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace newlines, you should use regex pattern `\r?\n`. This will match both *nix as well as Windows newlines.

In your template string however, there are multiple characters that have special meaning in regex, therefore you need to do `[regex]::Escape()`, but that also would wrongfully escape the characters `\r?\n`, rendering it as `\\r\?\\n`, so adding that in the $matchString *before* escaping it, would be of no use.

You can manually first replace the newline with a character that otherwise is not present in the $matchString and has no special meaning in regex.

```
$template = '<div class="tile-inspiration__title field-title">$fieldTool.GetFieldValue($i
tem,"Title")</div>'
# for demo, I chose to replace the newline with an underscore
$matchString = '$fieldTool.GetFieldValue($i_tem,"Title")'
# now, escape the string and after that replace the underscore by the wanted \r?\n pattern
$pattern = [regex]::escape($matchString) -replace '_', '\r?\n'
# $pattern is now: \$fieldTool\.GetFieldValue\(\$i\r?\ntem,"Title"\)
$replaceString = "{{(sc_get_field_value i_item 'Title')}}"

# this time, the replacement should work
$newtemplate = $template -replace $pattern, $replaceString
Write-Host $newtemplate  # --> <div class="tile-inspiration__title field-title">{{(sc_get_field_value i_item 'Title')}}</div>
```